# BeautifulSoup previous_sibling not working

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Some items have title but some don't, sample html like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <h5>Title1</h5>
    <div class="text">text 1</div>

    <h5>Title2</h5>
    <div class="text">text 2</div>

    <div class="text">text 3</div>

    <div class="text">text 4</div>
</div>
```

Tried to get all the class `text`, and get their titles `h5`(if any).

`find_previous_sibling` can get the title, but the last two `text` also list the title which is not owned by them.

and also tried `previous_sibling`, then judge whether it is `h5` or `div`, `h5` as title, but it returns nothing.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
content = html.find('div',{'id': 'content'})
paras = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'text'})

for para in paras:
    title = p.find_previous_sibling('h5')
    if title:
        print(title.get_text())

    pr = para.previous_sibling
    if pr:
        print(pr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find_previous()` without any params to get the DOM element before the `div`, then use `.name` to check if it's a `<h5>`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div id="content">
    <h5>Title1</h5>
    <div class="text">text 1</div>

    <h5>Title2</h5>
    <div class="text">text 2</div>

    <div class="text">text 3</div>
    <div class="text">text 4</div>
</div>
"""

html = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
content = html.find('div',{'id': 'content'})
paras = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'text'})

for para in paras:
    print(para.text)
    prev = para.find_previous()
    if prev and prev.name == 'h5':
        print(prev.text)
```

Gives:

```
text 1
Title1
text 2
Title2
text 3
text 4
```